# How construct MISO byte order with SPI interface

Tags: spi, rfid

I have a raspberry Pi 3, model B. I have an RFID-RC522 hooked up to it using SPI.
I want to read from it, raspi being master device, RFID being slave(MISO). I am struggling to construct the correct byte order. Spec sheet for rfid scanner: http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MFRC522.pdf

On page 10 and 11 the byte order and address byte is explained. And on page 70 the available commands. I am unsure how to construct correct MISO address byte, and how to implement the commands need to receive data from RFID chip.

```
 byte packet[] = new byte[2];
    packet[0] = READ_CMD;    // address byte
    packet[2] = 0b00000000;  // data byte
```

I should be able to send the data byte, and then it is returned with overwritten data.

```
System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("[TX] " + bytesToHex(packet));
    Spi.wiringPiSPIDataRW(0, packet, 2);
    System.out.println("[RX] " + bytesToHex(packet));
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
```

Method definition:
public static int wiringPiSPIDataRW(int channel,
                                    String data,
                                    int length)

Any help with constructing the byte packet to send with correct byte address and commands would be awesome. General explanation of how this all works would also be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You won't get anywhere until you understand how SPI works and for that you are best off googling for a tutorial.  Only you will know when you have found an explanation which is pitched at the right level.

Comment: MISO is a pin label/function, it means "Master In, Slave Out", there is also a corresponding MOSI (Master Out, Slave In) pin, a chip select, and a clock.  You don't construct "MISO" "address bytes". There is also no standard for the data format sent over SPI so this is entirely dependent on the RFID chip you are talking to.

Comment: `packet[2] = 0b00000000;  // data byte` is also a compiler error since your array is only 2 elements long, it should be `packet[1]`.

Comment: -joan I am just trying to understand some SPI examples i saw in the Pi4j library. Will keep learning tho!